# Ubuntu 23.10, return from sleep/suspend problems

Tags: drivers, suspend, power-management, 23.10

I'm on an Lenovo Ideapad, dual boot and having major problems returning from suspend, sometimes the computer will be on (not a totally dark screen as I had on Ubuntu 22.04, 23.04, and earlier versions).

I have stuff like DKMS for my Asus Wifi adapter installed as well as Display Link driver for USB monitor, Nvidia Cuda toolkit but are there certain things that can interfere with proper suspend?  I have it set so pushing the power button suspends the system.

Answer (score 2):

Find out what's going on by looking at the system's log messages.
First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`.

Comment: I turned off tracker3 so no longer have desktop icons but still get forced to log out so am running this: https://gist.github.com/nyck33/2c20c7b3f5fb4b80727626993b1d28e7 Thanks for your advice, it led me to also uninstall snap Firefox which was causing many AppArmor issues and logs to bloat to 181 GB but that script I'm hoping will catch whatever else is happening that should not be.