# What do I do if AppArmor and GNOME configuration seem to be interfering with normal suspend/resume in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, suspend, apparmor

Follow up to my other question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1492540/806813

I followed the advice and got some log output below.
Is there a magic wand?  I'm an app developer and have the utmost respect for systems developers but just want a quick solution for this problem.

On Ubuntu 23.10, going into suspend and coming back have errors, sometimes I get a message that I need to log out (maybe a crash), what does this log show where I pinned from just before suspending and then coming back:

```
base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
[sudo] password for nyck33: 
Nov 15 11:12:08 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[40862]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd-logind[1540]: Power key pressed short.
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriti>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt ModemManager[1668]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] s>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:343): p>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostnam>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:344): p>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostnam>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:345): p>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostnam>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:346): p>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostnam>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt google-chrome.desktop[43962]: [43956:43986:1115/11121>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.719:347): p>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostnam>
lines 1-23...skipping...
Nov 15 11:12:08 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[40862]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor">
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd-logind[1540]: Power key pressed short.
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt ModemManager[1668]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:343): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  >
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:344): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  >
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:345): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  >
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:346): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  >
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt google-chrome.desktop[43962]: [43956:43986:1115/111210.721509:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.719:347): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  >
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd-logind[1540]: The system will suspend now!
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7192] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7193] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[1494]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7286] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7288] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7290] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[1494]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 34:3d:c4:22:58:9a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=34:3d:c4:22:58:9a reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:e2cc:a3ff:a032:c62c on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:a192:a7ae:bb64:52a4 on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:a192:a7ae:bb64:52a4.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014331.0250] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Registering new address record for fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828 on wlo1.*.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828 on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.3.16 on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.3.16.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
lines 1-49















































Nov 15 11:12:08 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[40862]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMon>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd-logind[1540]: Power key pressed short.
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt gnome-shell[43225]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt ModemManager[1668]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:343): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sign>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:344): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sign>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:345): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sign>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.715:346): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sign>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt google-chrome.desktop[43962]: [43956:43986:1115/111210.721509:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700014330.719:347): pid=1494 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_sign>
                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd-logind[1540]: The system will suspend now!
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7192] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7193] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[1494]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by>
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7286] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7288] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014330.7290] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt dbus-daemon[1494]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 34:3d:c4:22:58:9a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Nov 15 11:12:10 nyck33-tt systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=34:3d:c4:22:58:9a reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt wpa_supplicant[1564]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:e2cc:a3ff:a032:c62c on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:a192:a7ae:bb64:52a4 on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address 2400:2410:8c82:1a00:a192:a7ae:bb64:52a4.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt NetworkManager[1563]: <info>  [1700014331.0250] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Registering new address record for fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828 on wlo1.*.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828 on wlo1.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::1128:6480:b39:1828.
Nov 15 11:12:11 nyck33-tt avahi-daemon[1492]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
lines 1-46
```

Edit: more info

```
(base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145557+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145575+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145593+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145611+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145628+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145646+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145664+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145682+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145700+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145717+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145735+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145753+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145772+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145789+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145807+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145825+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145843+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145862+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145879+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145897+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145915+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145933+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145952+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145970+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.145988+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146005+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146023+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146041+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146059+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146077+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146095+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146112+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146131+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146148+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146166+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146184+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146202+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146219+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146238+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146256+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146274+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146292+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146310+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146329+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146347+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146365+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146383+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146401+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146419+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146437+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146455+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146473+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146491+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146508+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146527+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146545+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146563+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146580+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146598+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146617+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146635+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146652+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146671+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146688+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146707+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146724+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146743+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146761+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146778+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146796+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146815+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146833+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146851+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146869+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146887+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146906+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146924+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146942+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146960+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146978+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.146997+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147015+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147033+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147051+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147069+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147087+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147105+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147123+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147141+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147159+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147176+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147195+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147213+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147231+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147249+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147267+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147285+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147303+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147320+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
2023-11-15T17:43:48.147338+09:00 nyck33-tt tracker-miner-f[4029]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
```

This command: `(base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ sudo cp /var/log/syslog ~/syslog.txt`  resulted in a file that is 83.6 GB until I ctrl-C'ed to stop it.  That is not right even I can tell.

Now I am going through steps to stop and restart tracker3

or try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1487341/806813

Edit2: did the above, stopped tracker and now did

```
(base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ ls -lh /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 181G Nov 15 18:12 /var/log/syslog
(base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog
```

181 GB for logs?  I had this same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 on this particular nvme type internal SSD, Sabrent is the manufacturer.  Could that be the culprit?  Ie. it's a hardware issue not software?

Edit 3: uninstalled snap Firefox, now did this:

`gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com` 
I'm pulling straws right?

Comment: I have no idea what to do so wrote and am running this: https://gist.github.com/nyck33/2c20c7b3f5fb4b80727626993b1d28e7